# Store some values between requests

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, apim

I have an API in Azure APIM. I want to persist a value between multiple client calls. Basically, this API is like a proxy where the actual business logic is in a different back-end API of a different system. Clients are routed through Azure APIM. The back-end API needs one value to be sent between requests which is dynamic based on authentication.

1. Client requests to Azure API
2. Azure APIM checks if the value required by the back-end API is available? if so sends the value with the request to the back-end API.
3. If not, Azure APIM calls the back-end API to get the value based on the authentication information and stores it and used in subsequent requests until the validity of the value expires.

Is it possible to do this in Azure APIM policies?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Please check out the send-request policy which returns the response as a variable: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-sample-send-request#send-request

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. The provided article discusses sending the token to the client. But in my case the token is used between Azure and the back-end API. Clients do not send token.

Comment: ok, I understand. So you want to cache some values? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-caching-policies

Comment: Yes, I would love to.

Comment: Do the caching policies fulfill your requirements? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-caching-policies

Comment: I see about response caching. It's not response caching, I'm sure you understand my requirement. Thanks a lot for the pointer. I'll do some further research.

Answer (score 0):

Use the **Send Request Policy** for multiple client calls/requests to check the value is available and use the Azure APIM [**validate policies**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/validation-policies) based on if it is coming in the ***Header*** or ***body path***.

Parsing and checking the value is also possible where you can use **Choose Policy** and then if it is not available, pick from the authentication.

Use **Store Cache** Policy to store the value for certain period of time and **Cache Lookup** to retrieve the value.

Refer to the Azure APIM [Caching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-caching-policies) and [advanced policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-advanced-policies).